# How to retrieve multiple value from an input using magicsearch with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input, autocomplete

I'm using the jquery library magicsearch to select multiple value in an inupt. I would like to know how to retrieve these values in a variable. 
My html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8 magicsearch" id="person" name="person" />
```

In jquery I tryed to used it but it retruns empty value:

```
var person = $('#person').val();
```

Comment: Can you please provide details like what you want to do? when you say 'select multiple value in an inupt' what are you exactly trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, I found it's documentation(https://www.dingyi1993.com/blog/magicsearch, which is not in English), as per the documentation the value is stored as `data-id` attribute, so get the selected value by getting the attribute value.

```
$('#person').attr('data-id')
```

*FYI :* if multiple choice, multiple The ids are separated by a comma(,).